# C++ Nested map: accessing inner map

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, reference

Why does accessing the inner map in a nested C++ map only sometimes update the value accessible through the outer map? Specifically, why do cases 1 and 3 in the code below not update the value `m[500]["text"]`?

My understanding is that indexing into the outer map in all of these cases returns a reference to inner map. So why does only the 2nd case update the outer map correctly? Do cases 1 and 3 get the value of the inner map instead of a reference to it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, map<string, int>> m1;
    map<int, map<string, int>> m2;
    map<int, map<string, int>> m3;
    
    auto inner = m1[500];
    inner["text"] = 10;
    
    map<string, int> *ptr = &m2[500];
    (*ptr)["text"] = 20;
    
    map<string, int> inner3 = m3[500];
    inner3["text"] = 30;
    
    cout << "inner  " << inner["text"] << " map " << m1[500]["text"] << endl;
    cout << "ptr    " << (*ptr)["text"] << " map " << m2[500]["text"] << endl;
    cout << "inner3 " << inner3["text"] << " map " << m3[500]["text"] << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out the following:

```
inner  10 map 0
ptr    20 map 20
inner3 30 map 0
```

I would expect all 3 to print non-0 values, but only the 2nd case does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto inner = m1[500];
...
map<string, int> inner3 = m3[500];
```

`auto` cannot deduce references. Both these statements will create copies of the inner map. Modifying those will just update the copy instead of the original value.

Use references in both cases to achieve the desired effect:

```
auto& inner = m1[500];
...
map<string, int>& inner3 = m3[500];
```

Comment: But why do these statements create copies of the inner map? Are maps not reference types in C++?

Comment: @TheBicPen There is no concept of "reference type" in C++. There may be classes such as `std::shared_ptr` that would have the same effect an reference type has for other languages. In C++ you can either choose to "add `&`" to a type or not. If you do add `&` the variable/return value provides information on the location of an object as chosen during the initialization of the reference. If you leave out the `&`, C++ will always attempt to convert the rhs of an assignment (or equivalent) to the left hand side using a constructor or an assignment operator. Thats why `map::operator[]`returns a ref

Comment: Basically "under the hood" references are pointers providing a different syntax for accessing the object, at least that's basically all compilers implement them. There are a few differences of course, e.g. not being able to dereference `nullptr`, at least not without casting it first, but being able to assign it to a pointer and being able to reassign a pointer.